# Rectangular instead of square output

Tags: pgfplots

It looks rectangular while it should be square ? any idea why?

```
\documentclass[borders=2cm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} 
   \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
     xlabel={x},
     ylabel={y},
     axis lines=left,
    axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.2},
    xmin = 0, xmax = 1.5,
    ymin = -1, ymax = 1.5,
    ytick={1},
    yticklabels={1},
    xtick= {1},
    xticklabels={1},                      
            ]
    \draw(0,1)--(1,1)--(1,0);

\end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ymin = 0 and it is squared

Comment: But it shouldn't effect

Comment: `axis equal image`

Comment: Yes, it affects because pgfplots sets  by default width and height of the image, and the scale of x and y coordinates is made to fit. If you want that the axis are equally scaled in units of the resulting image, use the key suggested by @HenriMenke

Comment: Use of `axis equal image` solves the issue, clearly. And btw, your global option for the document class should be `[border=2cm]` if you want it to be effective.